# TimeUUID vs timestamp in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, timeuuid

If we can extract time from TimeUUID, does it make any sense to use timestamp as another column in Cassandra?

Also how can we extract Time from TimeUUID and make range queries (eg. Jan 2016 to May 2016) on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to store `timestamp` in a different column, if you have chosen to use `timeuuid`.

You are looking for this:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html

Please take notice about the `min` and `max`. The LSB bits determine the uniqueness. i.e last 8 bits can range from `00000000` to `ffffffff`.

So please prepare your range query accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

From https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.0/cassandra/cql/cql_singlefile.html#timeuuidFun:

> Timeuuid functions
>
> `now`
>
> The `now` function takes no arguments and generates, on the coordinator node, a new unique timeuuid (at the time where the statement using it is executed). Note that this method is useful for insertion but is largely non-sensical in `WHERE` clauses. For instance, a query of the form
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE t = now()
> ```
>
> will never return any result by design, since the value returned by `now()` is guaranteed to be unique.
>
> `minTimeuuid` and `maxTimeuuid`
>
> The `minTimeuuid` (resp. `maxTimeuuid`) function takes a `timestamp` value `t` (which can be [either a timestamp or a date string](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.0/cassandra/cql/cql_singlefile.html#usingtimestamps)) and return a *fake*
> `timeuuid` corresponding to the *smallest* (resp. *biggest*) possible `timeuuid` having for timestamp `t`. So for instance:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE t > maxTimeuuid('2013-01-01 00:05+0000') AND t < minTimeuuid('2013-02-02 10:00+0000')
> ```
>
> will select all rows where the `timeuuid` column `t` is strictly older than `2013-01-01 00:05+0000` but strictly younger than `2013-02-02 10:00+0000`. Please note that `t >= maxTimeuuid('2013-01-01 00:05+0000')` would still *not* select a `timeuuid` generated exactly at `2013-01-01 00:05+0000` and is essentially equivalent to `t > maxTimeuuid('2013-01-01 00:05+0000')`.
>
> *Warning*: We called the values generated by `minTimeuuid` and `maxTimeuuid` *fake* UUID because they do no respect the Time-Based UUID generation process specified by the [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt). In particular, the value returned by these 2 methods will not be unique. This means you should only use those methods for querying (as in the example above). Inserting the result of those methods is almost certainly a *bad idea*.
>
> Time conversion functions
>
> A number of functions are provided to “convert” a `timeuuid`, a
> `timestamp` or a `date` into another native type.
>
> [image: Functions table]

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and converted during the query.

```
SELECT toTimestamp(uuid_timestamp) FROM table
```

It was not a problem because I was inserting into a panda dataframe for analysis.